# How can a centered <hr> be absolutely placed within a div, without losing its center alignment?

Tags: html, css

I need this

---

to be placed 20px from the bottom of the page, but every time I try to give it absolute positioning, it jumps halfway outside the div or it becomes longer.

It was centered using display:flex and justify-content:center. The exact same problem occurs with the socila icons, which need to be at the top on desktop and at the bottom on mobile, but if I give them an absolute position, then they are no longer centered.

Here is the entire page for you to see what I need, and thank you so much for your time:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/234b945d49.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#main-menu-container{
  right:0;
}

.sidenav {
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(#3d77a7, #264c6d);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidenav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 150px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sidenav ul a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav ul a:hover {
  color: #ffdc00;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color:#ffdc00;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-right .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
} */

#nav-icon3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span{ 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffdc00;
  border-radius: 1px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 12px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 24px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.social-icons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.social-icons i{
    color:#ffdc00;
    padding:5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.social-icons i:hover{
    color: white;
}
.menu-separator {
/*     position:relative;
    bottom:50px; */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 7px !important;
    opacity: 100%;
    color: #ffdc00; /* old IE */
    background: #ffdc00; /* Modern Browsers */
    width: 80%; 
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

.menu-additional-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.menu-additional-links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
    color: white;
}
.menu-additional-links a:hover{
    color: #ffdc00;
}

/*MOBILE BREAKPOINTS*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {


}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="main-menu-container">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" role="navigation">
        <div id="nav-icon3">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2xl"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square fa-2xl"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2xl"></i></a>
        </div>
        <hr class="menu-separator">
        <div class="menu-additional-links">
            <a href="#">Datenschutzerklärung</a>
            <a href="#">Impressum</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span class="breakpoint"></span>
  
</div>

<script>
    //check screen width via javascript, and pass a diffrent width to the nav menu 
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)')
    let menuWidth = "";  
    if (mediaQuery.matches){menuWidth = "500px";} else {menuWidth = "100vw";}
    function handleScreenChange(e){
        if (mediaQuery.matches){
        menuWidth = "500px";
        } else {
            menuWidth = "100vw";
        }
    }      
    mediaQuery.addListener(handleScreenChange);

    //set the width and play the animation on hamburger click
    $("#nav-icon3").click(function() {            
        if (document.getElementById('nav-icon3').classList.contains("open")){
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = menuWidth;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        }
        document.getElementById('nav-icon3').classList.toggle("open");
    });

</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this styles to hr

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 10%;
```

You have 80% for the width, so a left of 10% makes hr centered

Comment: Perfect, I'm ashamed that didn't occur to me.

I wonder if there's a less hacky way of fixing the social icons as well, other than giving them a margin-left of about 39%

Comment: Actually I just set the social-menu div to 100% width, set the margin to 0, and increased the z-index of the hamburger icon, and now it's perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: Sometimes it happens. It's right in front of you and you don't see it. Glad to help